# Keep checkbox unchecked until onclick function returns true with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox, angular-directive

Using **AngularJS** framework, in my **HTML** code I have this checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="switch.isOn()" ng-click="SwitchController.setValue()">
```

When clicked, the checkbox is checked/unchecked before the `setValue` function get executed. I want the checkbox not to be checked if the `setValue()` function returns `false` value.

Comment: Could you please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=mVEdag3eBL though it does not use AngularJS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value` along with `ng-model`.
If you get false value from your function just set the `ng-model` to constant you've specified in `ng-false-value`. 
Also you can use `ng-disabled` and set it true for the duration between right after entering the `SwitchController.setValue()` and the same function returning the value to prevent unwanted clicks.
This won't exactly delay the clicking of checkbox but should get you the desired end result.